# redmine session disorder after migration

Tags: ruby, session, rake, passenger, redmine

recently , I migrated redmine-2.3.2 from one machine(ruby 2.0.0-p247 centos6) to another(ruby 2.0.0p353 rhel7)

I installed the ruby gems, dumped the mysql database ,and then copied the redmine directory, and finally run it with apache+passenger

everything seems ok except that:

some people find that sometimes their session become another one's, for example:
A login as A, but after a while, when he reload the page, the login account become B

I did "rake generate_secret_token;rake tmp:cache:clear;rake tmp:sessions:clear" and restarted apache, but it was no use.

any one can help find out what's the problem?

Comment: Which version of Passenger are you running?

Comment: Does this problem occur too on 4.x? Does the problem occur on specific pages only, or can it happen on any page?

Comment: I will have a try with 4.x.  the problem occcurs on any page

Comment: This might be a bug in Phusion Passenger 5. I am the author. Version 5 is not yet considered production ready, which is why it is beta. So could you send a message to the mailing list? That way I can help you better.

Comment: fixed by using stable version. thx a lot

Comment: I've confirmed that this is a bug in Passenger 5. It has been [fixed](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/77ef4b0ecd69f8979e35a88c0521c2c6ffbe0c80) just now, and the fix will be available in 5.0 beta 3.